# Abstract Class in Smalltalk-Squeak. What is it?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

If I got it right so an Abstract Class is one which has at least one abstract method?

Now, if it's abstract so I am supposed to be unable to make instances of that Class?

Like, said `Abst` is a name of an abstract class (because it contains an abstract method) so doing:

```
a := Abst new.
```

is illegal and should pop-up an error/exception?
or the problem should arise here:

```
a := Abst class new.
```

?

UPDATE:
As suggested, I have made the next method which won't let the user to make instances of a Class but it doesn't work:

```
makeAbstract: aClass    
    aClass compile: 'new
                ^ self subclassResponsibility'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to Smalltalk! One of the great things about Smalltalk is that it trusts developers, who benefit from the power that comes with that trust. So words like "unable to" and "illegal" rarely apply.

Like most other things, Abstract classes in Smalltalk are more like a suggestion/pointer than a rigid law. The two clues you look for are #subclassResponsibility and #shouldNotImplement. These two methods are clues to subclassers whether or not to include a particular method. Check senders for examples in the image (always a great starting point for questions).

Since "abstract", as described above, is really on a per-method basis, your examples would not generate an error (unless #subclassResponsibility or #shouldNotImplement is called from initialize.

Two small things:

- Class names are capitalized in
  Smalltalk, so Abst, not abst.
- A google search goes a long way. Three
  out of the four top links for
  "smalltalk abstract class" were all
  you need ([this one](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/blog/blogView?entry=3456032325) in particular looked right on).

UPDATE: if you want to signal to users of your class that they should not create instances (like in your comment below), you could write:

```
Abstract>>new
    ^ self subclassResponsibility.
```

Then "Abstract new" -> error, but "AbstractSubclass new" is okay.

Although there is still no guarantee that AbstractSubclass has overridden the abstract method (not #new, but the one that caused you to want to prevent instancing in the first place), in practice this will not be a problem. If you *really* wanted to, you could put a check, maybe in #initialize, that makes sure none of the instance's methods call #subclassResponsibility, but don't bother unless you have good reason.

UPDATE 2: Your utility method to make a class abstract would be:

```
Class>>makeAbstract

    self class compile: 'new
                ^ self subclassResponsibility'.
```

Comment: Thanks, so if there's no such thing as "illegal" or "unable" what is actually the connection between an Abstract Class to not making instances of such class? If for example, I have a Class and I add an Abstract Method in runtime and then (still in runtime) when I will try to make an instance of that class I want it to generate an error so it won't let me to make that instance. Where should it be handled?

Comment: @Sean DeNigris, I've tried doing so but I got no errors when calling new. See update above.

Comment: You were very close. See my edit to the method body above (added "class"). Your code put #new on the instance side. Also, if you put it in Class, you don't have to pass the class name.

Comment: @Sean DeNigris, Thanks now it works. So what I did was adding to the instance? When I just did  aClass compile: 'somecode' for other methods I could see in the browser that the method was added so it did add methods without addind "class" as you wrote. What's the difference? And yeah, I know that the class name is not needed but makeAbstract is method that I added on my own Class and not in Class itself.

Comment: @Sean DeNigris, Is this has anything to do with the metaClass?

Comment: The method that you wrote did add the method, but on the instance-side. When you add "class", it adds it on the class-side. The details are really a whole other question, and can best be understood by reading a good Smalltalk reference. Lastly, putting the method in Class instead of in your class was a suggestion. This way you can write Abstract makeAbstract. AnotherAbstractClass makeAbstract. etc...

Comment: @user550413 you can send the message isAbstractClass to a class to find out if its abstract and then take any action you want. isAbstractClass returns true if any methods returns subclassResponsibility.

Answer (score 3):

In Smalltalk you can just instantiate abstract classes. As long as you do not call abstract methods it just works. You might want to implement missing methods at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an abstract class should have at least one abstract method, but no, you can still make instances of that class.

What you should do is make concrete classes which inherit from the abstract class which you can make instances of and call methods on.

Abstract methods in Smalltalk have a particular implementation which make them and the class abstract:

```
method
    self subclassResponsibility
```

This also means that subclasses should override this method and provide a concrete implementation.

If you see an error regarding subclassResponsibility your code has either called a method on the abstract class, or your subclass has not provided an implementation for the method.

Comment: I added a method that overrides new of some Class with  ^ self subclassResponsibility but still I got no errors when trying to make an instance of that Class (see code in the UPDATE above).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read the Pharo By Example book. You can find it here: http://pharobyexample.org/
and you will find a lot of interesting stuff. It is an open book, free, and you can download the pdf.
In fact, what you are asking is explained in chapter 5, page 88.

Answer (score 2):

The (fixed) "new-blocker" introduces a slight inconvenience for its concrete subclasses: they will have to redefine *new*, and cannot make use of any inherited superclasses' *new* functionality.
You can get around this with a little guard which checks if it is really the abstract class that is tried to be instantiated:

```
AbstractClass class >> new
    self == AbstractClass ifTrue:[
        ^ self abstractClassInstantiationError
    ].
    ^ super new
```

(notice the identity-compare here, which works even if you have stacked multiple abstract classes on top of each other)

Comment: You can see a similar problem (and solution) with abstract `TestCase`s in SUnit: look for implementors of `#isAbstract`.